# parsing a webpage contents in netbeans

Tags: java, ajax, jsoup, html-parsing, htmlunit

I'm working in netbeans 8.2 to get all content of this [webpage](http://www.igi-global.com/book/analyzing-strategic-role-social-networking/147123) 
I successfully got everything except for chapters because it's ajax call 
I used Jsoup lib and tried different library like HtmlUnit
if it possible to get all content from ajax call tell me even with different library

Comment: Please punctuate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick check using wetator (www.wetator.org) and was able to get that side including all the chapters. Wetator uses HtmlUnit so you will be able to do the same with Wetator or with plain HtmlUnit.
If you use HtmlUnit take care to add proper wait code.